# Ozzie workflow fork join actions share variables having same name or they have their own copy

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, oozie

I have Ozzie fork join workflow having hive query with variables like hr and day and passing them to hive query will these actions create separate hive session for query execution or there is danger of variables overwriting .

Thanks

```
<fork name = "fork_node">
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d00"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d01"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d02"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d03"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d04"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d05"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d06"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d07"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d08"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d09"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d10"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d12"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d13"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d14"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d15"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d16"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d17"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d18"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d19"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d20"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d21"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d22"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d23"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d24"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d00"/>
  <path start = "Create_local_Table-d00"/>
  <path start = "Create_orc_Table"/>
</fork>

<action name="loadDailyPartitionToLocalStaging" cred='hive_credentials'>
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
<script>/data/acs/hch/equipBatch/workflows/DataCleanup/TestWorkflowQa/loadDailyPartitionToLocalStaging.hql</script>
        <param>hiveconf:year=${year}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:month=${month}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:day=${day}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:year_r=${year_r}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:month_r=${month_r}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:day_r=${day_r}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:year_l=${year_l}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:month_l=${month_l}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:day_l=${day_l}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:partitonDate=${partitonDate}</param>
        <file>${wfpath}/TestWorkflowQa/tez-site.xml</file>
    </hive>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>


<action name="loadDailyPartitionToLocalStaging" cred='hive_credentials'>
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
<script>/data/acs/hch/equipBatch/workflows/DataCleanup/TestWorkflowQa/loadDailyPartitionToLocalStaging.hql</script>
        <param>hiveconf:year=${year}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:month=${month}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:day=${day}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:year_r=${year_r}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:month_r=${month_r}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:day_r=${day_r}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:year_l=${year_l}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:month_l=${month_l}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:day_l=${day_l}</param>
        <param>hiveconf:partitonDate=${partitonDate}</param>
        <file>${wfpath}/TestWorkflowQa/tez-site.xml</file>
    </hive>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
```

Comment: All the start path you have specified into the `fork` action should be defined as action in the workflow. Each of these action will execute in parallel into their own space so there is no variable overwrite issue. Also, `loadDailyPartitionToLocalStaging` you have defined two action with same name, please fix that as well. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, is there any setting which can control how many parallel fork join actions should run concurrently ?

Comment: It will execute the action defined into fork action. You can define multiple fork-join for controlling that. Thanks.